# Move camera to heat map display on the googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap

I am working on the google map to display Heat Map

I am able to display the Heat Map but I need to move the map to see my heat map. So right now I am using LatLngBounds to move the camera on the map. But I am getting a white grid screen because the map is not loading.

I am getting LatLong fro the text file and it has more than 5000 points.

Here is my effort

Adding heatmap using the **WeightedLatLng**

```
//Method for adding Heat Map overlay to existing map with heat map points from RoamIO
   
public void addHeatMap(final List<WeightedLatLng> list) {
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .weightedData(list)
            .build();
    storageAccess.logMessage("Adding heat map");
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mOverlay = mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));

            zoom2HeatMap(list);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my **zoom2HeatMap** method

```
    public void zoom2HeatMap(List<WeightedLatLng> list){

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 20; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cu, 2000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Here you can take the snapshot or whatever you want
            roamIO.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    });
}
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Any Help much appreciated

Thank You

Comment: You may have figured this out by now, but the `Point`.x and y (from `WeightedLatLng`) are not latlng values but the original latlngs projected onto an x/y plane using a SphericalMercatorProject.  This is done to more easily manage the heat map buckets but cannot be used as LatLngs.  You'll have to in some way access the original latlng data for the corresponding point.  I can assist further but if you already got the solution then not needed.  So the LatLngBuilder code in `zoom2git` is not correct since you are not using LatLngs but x/y points.

Comment: @Andy Thank you for the response. no I didn't got the solution and I change the parm to WeightedLatLng list in zoom method. You can see in my updated post

Comment: Your update doesn't show any LatLng points being `include`d in the builder.  But that is secondary to the fact that you cannot use the WeightedLatLng data as LatLng -  you'll need the original LatLng values (post how the WeightedLatLng list is created) to `include` with the builder.  Again, the WeightedLatLng `points` are strictly for heatmaps and are cannot be used for LatLngBounds.Builder.

Comment: Is there any way that I can convert WeightedLatLng to LatLng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches to accessing LatLng from the `List<WeightedLatLng> list`.  (This could be viewed as a shortcoming of that class that it didn't simply save the original LatLng.)

I can expand if any one is of interest.  In any event, it would be helpful if you could post how the `WeightedLatLng` list is created since that would help in the first option.

### Maintain a separate list

When creating your `List<WeightedLatLng> list` also create a `List<LatLng> latlngList` which you can then use for `LatLngBounds.Builder`.  These two lists would have the same structure - same length, etc. - and there would be several ways to do this.

### Extend WeightedLatLng

It appears not to be a final class so you could extend `WeightedLatLng` and override the constructors to save the supplied LatLng as a field and then invoke super class constructors.  Here you simply are adding that LatLng to your extended version of the WeightedLatLng (which they probably should have done in the first place).

### Use SphericalMercatorProjection

Use a class in the same android-maps-utils to convert your x/y point (from WeightLatLng) back to a LatLng.  You can look at the [source](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=googlemaps%2Fandroid-maps-utils%2Fandroid-maps-utils-master%2Fdemo%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fmaps%2Fandroid%2Futils%2Fdemo%2FHeatmapsDemoActivity.java#) for WeightLatLng to see they use the `SphericalMercatorProjection` and then do the inverse (using the `toLatLng` method).  Since its instance of the `SphericalMercatorProjection` is private you'd have to create your own instance (as is done in the source) using the `WorldWidth` constant.  This doesn't seem to bad so I'd probably go this route.  However, I can't guarantee that it is symmetric to the precision you may require.  (i.e. A => B => A', where A ~= A' - I'd probably run some tests.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Andy I think I should generate separate LatLng list would be a good idea.

Comment: Good luck - I agree the separate list is how'd approach it - (but I'm curious about the transitive nature  of the projection class so I'll experiment with that and update for my own benefit.)

Comment: if you got that working then I can give that as a right answer. But please post as seperate answer because this is good explanation.

Comment: Hi you look like an expert in google map Would you like to answer this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137401/keep-track-values-between-markers

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer, the `SphericalMercatorProjection` can be used to convert the `com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.WeightedLatLng` point back to a LatLng.  The WeightedLatLng implementation uses an instance of this class to convert the supplied LatLng to a x/y point used in heat map tallying but does not expose its instance.  So a new instance is required using the same "world width" parameter of 1. (The worldWidth parameter affects the scaling of the x/y coordinate system and would adversely affect the inverse if two different world widths were used.)

In my implementation of a heat map of crime data around San Francisco I simply added the use of the `toLatLng` from the WeightedLatLnt.getPoint() and found the inverse operation is nearly consistent, at least for that portion of the sphere:

```
// Create an instance of the projection class using the same "world width" value used as the WeightedLatLng implementation.
SphericalMercatorProjection smp = new SphericalMercatorProjection(1);  // Size of the world (arbitrary).

// Method which gets a list of WeightedLatLngs and uses a parallel list of LatLngs -
// and for this snippet also logs the conversion of the WeightedLatLng back to LatLng using the toLatLng of projection class.
public void addWeightedDots() {
    List<WeightedLatLng> dots = new CrimeData().getWeightedPositions();
    List<LatLng> positions = new CrimeData().getPositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i++) {
        Log.i(TAG,"pos="+positions.get(i)+" wLL="+dots.get(i).getPoint()+" toLatLng="+smp.toLatLng(dots.get(i).getPoint()));
    }
    // ... more irrelevant code....
}
```

And some sample output:

```
pos=lat/lng: (38.48538062,-121.5374388) wLL=Point{x=0.16239600333333332, y=0.38401196188724207} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.48538062,-121.5374388)
pos=lat/lng: (38.55462435,-121.458819) wLL=Point{x=0.16261439166666664, y=0.3837661209021186} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.55462434999998,-121.458819)
pos=lat/lng: (38.61474191,-121.4461725) wLL=Point{x=0.16264952083333334, y=0.3835524891142911} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.61474191,-121.4461725)
pos=lat/lng: (38.54221766,-121.4374105) wLL=Point{x=0.1626738597222222, y=0.38381018666163447} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.54221766,-121.43741050000001)
pos=lat/lng: (38.61295423,-121.5005071) wLL=Point{x=0.1624985913888889, y=0.38355884433643966} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.61295422999999,-121.5005071)
pos=lat/lng: (38.60307405,-121.420291) wLL=Point{x=0.1627214138888889, y=0.3835939656295897} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.60307404999999,-121.420291)
pos=lat/lng: (38.47433721,-121.4189709) wLL=Point{x=0.1627250808333333, y=0.3840511482481476} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.474337209999995,-121.4189709)
pos=lat/lng: (38.45471595,-121.4381169) wLL=Point{x=0.1626718975, y=0.38412075739044343} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.45471595,-121.4381169)
pos=lat/lng: (38.52555366,-121.43427) wLL=Point{x=0.16268258333333335, y=0.38386936146458267} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.52555366,-121.43427)
pos=lat/lng: (38.62147929,-121.4278524) wLL=Point{x=0.16270040999999996, y=0.38352853623062677} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.62147929,-121.42785240000002)
pos=lat/lng: (38.47614715,-121.4598152) wLL=Point{x=0.16261162444444444, y=0.38404472628068015} toLatLng=lat/lng: (38.47614715,-121.45981520000001)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I am generating the LatLng list to zoom. Thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: I didn’t try this solution so i am gone a mark top one as a right answer.